# Bootstrap dropdown breaking across css columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

The page I'm working on originally used the Bootstrap 3 grid system (ex: col-md-3), but due to some ordering constraints, the client wants the ordering of the fields to be vertically stacked into two columns.  I figured css columns would be the way to go.  For the most part it's working out well, but as you can see in the image, my dropdowns, if they're long enough, will break across columns.  Ideally the dropdown would just continue overlaying the container div.

[image: Dropdown breaking across columns]

Here's the HTML for that section shrunken down to just the dropdown and container (taken from the chrome dev tools)

```
<div class="fieldSection ng-scope">                
    <div ng-repeat="field in group.TransportFields | orderBy:'Ord'" class="ng-scope">
        <div class="detailField">
            <label class="wrap-text control-label col-md-5 ng-scope ng-binding" ng-show="true" for="CATALOG.COUNTRY" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="Country the program originally aired in">Country</label>
            <div ng-switch="field.InputType" ng-class="field.ID=='DIGITIZE.COPIES' ? 'col-md-20' : 'col-md-15'" class="col-md-15">                    
                <div ng-switch-when="Enumeration" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="btn-group col-md-20 open">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-enum dropdown-toggle ng-binding" id="CATALOG.COUNTRY + '-dd'" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu detailDropdown" role="menu" aria-labelledby="CATALOG.COUNTRY + '-dd'">
                            <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="item in enumFields[field.ID]" class="ng-scope"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-mv="1" ng-click="$parent.field.Value = item.Value" class="ng-binding"></a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="item in enumFields[field.ID]" class="ng-scope"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-mv="2" ng-click="$parent.field.Value = item.Value" class="ng-binding">United States</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="item in enumFields[field.ID]" class="ng-scope"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-mv="3" ng-click="$parent.field.Value = item.Value" class="ng-binding">Afghanistan</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="item in enumFields[field.ID]" class="ng-scope"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-mv="197" ng-click="$parent.field.Value = item.Value" class="ng-binding">Zimbabwe</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: field in group.TransportFields | orderBy:'Ord' -->
</div>
```

and the LESS that applies

```
input, textarea, button, table, ul {
   -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;        
   break-inside:avoid;
}

.fieldSection, .workOrderSection {
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-gap: 2em;
   -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
   column-gap: 2em;
   -moz-column-width: 20em;
   -webkit-column-width: 20em;
   column-width: 20em;
   -webkit-column-span: none;
   column-span: none;    
}

.detailField {
   -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;        
   break-inside:avoid;

   > div {
      margin: 1px 0px;
   }

   label {
      padding-top: 3px;
      padding-left: 4px;
      font-size: 12px;
      height: 20px;
   }

   button,
   input {
      font-size: 12px;
   }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Any luck with this one? Having the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately no.  I wound up just not using css-columns and changing the layout